# How to add google maps api key correctly

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, api-key

Actually I'm running my geocoding function on my website with this code:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
```

This works perfect but it runs only with a few addresses per day. To get more lat/lng coordinates per day I have created an geocoding API key.

But I don't know how to add that key inside my existing code that it will run properly.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MY_GEOCODE_API_KEYaddress=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put &'s between each set of parameters in a URL (like you did with "sensor=false") and use the secure protocol (https://):

Instead of:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MY_GEOCODE_API_KEYaddress=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
```

use:

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MY_GEOCODE_API_KEY&address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
```

[example without key](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York,%20NY&sensor=false)

[example with invalid key](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York,%20NY&sensor=false&key=fdsasdfja)

(note that when I use a key but not the ["https" protocol](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York,%20NY&sensor=false&key=fdsasdfja), I get a different message:"error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL.")

Comment: Thanks, but this changes nothing. I get not more lat/lng coordinates.

Comment: But does it answer your question?

Comment: Don't know, because it changes nothing. I don'get get more coordinates back so I can't say if this ist right or wrong. Actually I must say it don't answer my question.